# Can I customize Finder to have distinct sounds for moving files vs. copying files?

Tags: macos, finder, audio

I frequently both copy (Alt-Drag) and move (Drag) files in Finder from one directory to another. My dexterity isn't so great, and so sometimes I accidentally let go of the Alt key before the mouse button is released (meaning that I might have moved a file, whereas I actually wanted to copy it).

It seems to me that a good way to distinguish between these two events, meaning I don't need to go back and check in the source directory, would be for Finder to have two distinct sound effects for them.

Is it possible to customise the Finder sound effects so that Move and Copy have distinct sounds?

I am on OS X 10.9, for the record, but a solution with wider applicability, in particular for 10.10, would be preferred.